# Add enclosing class to Eclipse template

Tags: android, eclipse

I do many logging in Android, so I want to create an Eclipse template for quick logging. This is my template :

Name: log

Pattern: Log.d("${enclosing_package}", "${enclosing_method}" +${cursor});

I need to add enclosing class to log info but there is no $enclosing_class. Is there any way to get enclosing_class?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want ${enclosing_type}.

The complete list of template variables is available in [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-template-variables.htm).